# Installing pygame with homebrew

Tags: python, pygame, homebrew

I am trying to install pygame for Python3 using Homebrew. (I have both Python 2 and Python 3 on my machine.)

I used [this Reddit page](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/21tp7n/how_to_install_pygame_on_osx_mavericks/), which says:

```
brew tap Homebrew/python
brew update
brew install pygame
```

This works perfect and installs `pygame` successfully on my Python 2.7. However, Python 3 still does not have `pygame`.

I also found that I can do it using `pip3`. However, I am looking for a way to install pygame for Python 3 using Homebrew.

Comment: Why not use pip3? Especially since the homebrewn pygame2 will have installed the necessary libraries for pygame, it could be very straightforward to install pygame with pip3. Alternatively, you may want to edit the homebrew formula and create your own, replacing Python 2 with Python 3.

Comment: Installing Pygame for Python 3 on OS X was never quite that simple.

Comment: check `brew info pygame`. It has a `--with-python3` option.

Comment: @cel, thanks for the answer. However, `brew install pygame --with-python3` does not work. It says: `Warning: homebrew/python/pygame-1.9.2a0 already installed`.

Comment: @Sait, have you tried uninstalling before trying to install again?

Comment: @cel, Wow! It actually worked. Can you please post an answer below so that I can accept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `--with-python3` is the key here. You can install via `brew install --with-python3`.

In general `brew info <package-name>` will give you additional information. In this case `brew info pygame` prints:

```
homebrew/python/pygame: stable 1.9.2a0, HEAD
http://pygame.org
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-python/blob/master/pygame.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: sdl ✔, sdl_image ✔, sdl_mixer ✔, sdl_ttf ✘, smpeg ✘, jpeg ✔, libpng ✔, portmidi ✘, homebrew/python/numpy ✘, freetype ✔
==> Options
--with-python3
    Build with python3 support
--without-python
    Build without python2 support
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
```

Answer (score 1):

Homebrew might be the tool you need to get this done. But first;

- Do you have homebrew installed?
  To check, in your terminal, type in brew. A list of commands should follow. If not install homebrew, here https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.11-el-capitan, and follow the homebrew instructions section
- Once homebrew is setup, run 'brew update'
- Then run 'brew install pygame'. It might prompt you install 'homebrew/python/pygame' instead, copy that command and run it